# The contents of the nav-button does not show up when I click on the buttons. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Below is a js code of a basic website with various navigation button at the top of the page. There are contents associated with each of the nav buttons and when I click on the bottns, I expect to see the contents assigned to each.

```
// Show/hide content containers when navigation buttons are clicked
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
// Get all the navigation buttons
const navButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-button");

// Get all the content containers
const contentContainers = document.querySelectorAll(".content-container");

// Add click event listeners to each button
navButtons.forEach((button, index) => {
    button.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // Hide all the content containers
        contentContainers.forEach((container) => {
            container.style.display = "none";
        });

        // Show the content container corresponding to the clicked button
        const targetId = button.getAttribute('href');
        const targetContent = document.querySelector(targetId + '-content');

        // Check if the content container exists
        if (targetContent) {
            targetContent.style.display = "block";
            }
        });
    });
});

// Form submission handling
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    const contactForm = document.getElementById('contact-form');
    if (contactForm) {
       contactForm.addEventListener('submit', handleFormSubmission);
   }
});

function handleFormSubmission(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Replace the following lines with your desired form submission logic
    const formData = new FormData(event.target);
    const name = formData.get('name');
    const email = formData.get('email');
    const message = formData.get('message');
    console.log(`Name: ${name}, Email: ${email}, Message: ${message}`);
    alert('Thank you for your submission! We will get in touch soon.');
    event.target.reset(); // Reset the form after submission
}


When i click on the nac buttons e,g, About Us, I expected to see the contents associated with that 
        button e.g.  <div id="about-content" class="content-container">
        <h2>About Us</h2>
        <p>Welcome to Chick Ventures. We are a leading venture capital firm...</p>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Could you provide some of your html and css code? Their might be errors there but I'll also be able to see the navbar.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect
`const targetId = button.getAttribute('href');`

is not returning what you want - have you tried console logging it to verify?

Perhaps you want to set the value as the element's `id` rather than `href` - your variable name suggests that might have been your plan.

I am not sure if your nav buttons are `button` elements or `a` tags - only `a` tags can have the `href` attribute.  But I think it will still not return what you expect - it will construct a file path.